# Iterate Multiple input array form values in asp.net 5 controller action

Tags: asp.net

```
<div class="form-group">
@{
  for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
    { 
      <input id="mondayM" name="StartTime[]" 

       type="text" class="time monday M" />

    }
}
</div>
```

" i am repeating input values as i have to take 7 values.How can i iterate it in controller action to get 7 values"

Comment: are you using model or formcollection in controller?

Comment: Please tell me how to iterate in controller action as                                         " public ActionResult BusinessTiming(ICollection<DoctorSchedule> ds){}".There DoctorSchedule is my model class.

Comment: i am using model class(DoctorSchedule).Also i used array properties{get,set}

Answer (score 0):

use an array or list in your model eg: List mondayM { get; set; }
in your view change id="mondayM" to id="mondayM[@i]"

Hopefully this example will help:

```
// Model

public class DoctorSchedule
{
    public string Something { get; set; }
}

public class DoctorScheduleModel
{
    public IList<DoctorSchedule> DoctorSchedules { get; set; }
    public DoctorScheduleModel()
    {
        DoctorSchedules = new List<DoctorSchedules>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            DoctorSchedules.Add(new DoctorSchedule());
        } 
    }
}

// Controller

public class DoctorScheduleController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(DoctorScheduleModel model)
    {
        foreach (DoctorSchedule doctorSchedule in model.DoctorSchedules)
        {
            var x = doctorSchedule.Something;
        }
    }
}

// View

@model DoctorScheduleModel

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.DoctorSchedules.Count; i++)
@{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.DoctorSchedules[i].Something)
@}
```

Comment: Please tell me how to iterate in controller action as                                         " public ActionResult BusinessTiming(ICollection<DoctorSchedule> ds){}".There DoctorSchedule is my model class.

Comment: Use a foreach loop in the controller.

Comment: Error is came as "can't implicitly convert from string to string[]" when i write      string[] mondayM=modelobject.mondayM;

Comment: Could you tell me iterative code(foreachloop and code elements ).Thank u

Comment: I have added a loop to the model to initialise the list with 7 schedules. The code in the controller will iterate all items in the list.